# Why the system don't swap?

Tags: linux, swap, arm, ram

I build some software on an armv7 with 1 GB RAM installed. It seems, that some builds need too much RAM:

[image]

And the build get RIP and with `internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)`.

So I am enlarge the swap by adding a swapfile, like it is described here http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/how-to-add-swap-space/ in method 2.

But as you can see in the picture. The RAM is filled up near by 100% but the system don't make a swap. If there a possibility to correct or to force it?

Thanks in advance
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo 100 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness